# CSS only 3D spinning text

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a div with some text spinning. How do I get the text depth to give a better 3d effect? To clarify, at `90deg` the text becomes `1px` thick because we can only see it from the side - how do I make it, eg, `10px` thick? Also, the appropriate amount of depth should be shown - i.e. at `0deg` we don't see the depth; at `45deg` we see `5px` of depth; at `90deg` we see the full `10px` depth; etc.

**I am after a CSS only solution.**

```css
#spinner {
  animation-name: spinner;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  text-align:center;
}
@keyframes spinner {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="spinner">Stop, I'm getting dizzy!</p>
```

Comment: Gah! Which direction is it spinning? My brain can't make up its mind. XD

Comment: Hi Is this what you mean http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/3d-transforms/ while the text is in 90deg the thickness should show like that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Simple `text-shadow` can do the trick:

```css
body {
  perspective: 500px;
}
#spinner {
  text-align: center;
  animation-name: spin, depth;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}
@keyframes spin {
  from { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotateY(-360deg); }
}
@keyframes depth {
  0% { text-shadow: 0 0 black; }
  25% { text-shadow: 1px 0 black, 2px 0 black, 3px 0 black, 4px 0 black, 5px 0 black; }
  50% { text-shadow: 0 0 black; }
  75% { text-shadow: -1px 0 black, -2px 0 black, -3px 0 black, -4px 0 black, -5px 0 black; }
  100% { text-shadow: 0 0 black; }
}
```

```html
<p id="spinner">Stop, I'm getting dizzy!</p>
```

Another improvement could be to clone the text using `::before` and `::after` pseudo-classes:

```css
body {
  perspective: 1000px;
}
#spinner {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  animation-name: spin, depth;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}
#spinner::before,
#spinner::after {
  content: "Stop, I'm getting dizzy!";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotateY(0.5deg);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}
#spinner::after {
  transform: rotateY(-0.5deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}
@keyframes spin {
  from { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotateY(-360deg); }
}
@keyframes depth {
  0% { text-shadow: 0 0 black; }
  25% { text-shadow: 1px 0 black, 2px 0 black, 3px 0 black, 4px 0 black, 5px 0 black, 6px 0 black; }
  50% { text-shadow: 0 0 black; }
  75% { text-shadow: -1px 0 black, -2px 0 black, -3px 0 black, -4px 0 black, -5px 0 black, -6px 0 black; }
  100% { text-shadow: 0 0 black; }
}
```

```html
<p id="spinner">Stop, I'm getting dizzy!</p>
```

Comment: from the (RUN CODE SNIPPET) we can see that the scroll bar below it gets activated. The spin should be in fixed div (max-width,min-width,width) to avoid it.

Answer (score 5):

A pure CSS solution will not look good. For a truly 3D effect, use JS. I recommend using `three.js`, because it has a fairly easy-to-use `textGeometry` function included.

I have written a script that replaces contents of elements with class `rotatingText` with a webGL scene where the text that was inside the element is rotating.

You can of course do all kinds of cool effects with three.js also to make your text [look nicer](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_text.html#FB00FF3100#I'm%20getting%20dizzy!). See [textGeometry doc](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/TextGeometry) for text formatting. Look in the [three.js docs](http://threejs.org/docs/) for further details.

I put in some notes in the comments of the code.

```css
.rotatingText {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!--your rotating text, just give it class rotatingText-->
<div class="rotatingText">Stop, I'm getting dizzy!</div>


<!--three.js library-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/threejs/r69/three.min.js"></script>
<!--the default font for three.js-->
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.js"></script>
<!--the script that converts each .rotatingText element into 3D -->
<script>
  function rotateText(container,i){
    var t = THREE;
    var containerW = container.offsetWidth;
    var containerH = container.offsetHeight;
    var theText = container.innerHTML; //grab the text from the element...
    container.innerHTML = ""; // ...and clear it
    var renderer = new t.WebGLRenderer({
      alpha: true,
      antialiasing: true
    });
    renderer.setSize(containerW, containerH);
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    var scene = new t.Scene();
    var camera = new t.PerspectiveCamera(
      75, //vertical field of view
      containerW / containerH, //aspect ratio
      0.1, //near plane
      1000 //far plane
    );
    scene.add(camera);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 100);
    // This is your 3D text:
    var geometry = new t.TextGeometry(theText, { //insert the text we grabbed earlier here
      size: 10, //your font size
      height: 1 //your font depth
    });
    var material = new t.MeshLambertMaterial({
      color: 0x000000 //your font color
    });
    var text = new t.Mesh(geometry, material); //this is your 3D text object
    //I created a pivot object to act as the center point for rotation:
    geometry.computeBoundingBox();
    var textWidth = geometry.boundingBox.max.x - geometry.boundingBox.min.x;
    text.position.set(-0.5 * textWidth, 0, 0);
    scene.add(text);
    var pivot = new t.Object3D();
    pivot.add(text);
    scene.add(pivot);
    //Then just render your scene and request for new frames
    this.render = function() {
      pivot.rotation.y += .02; //how much you want your text to rotate per frame
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    render();
  }

  var rotatingTextElements = document.getElementsByClassName("rotatingText");
  for (var i = 0; i < rotatingTextElements.length; i++) {
    rotateText(rotatingTextElements[i]);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I am aware of three.js, however I am after a CSS only solution.

Answer (score 3):

Adding multiple clones of the original element , each translated 1px behind, and then working on their color to give a 3d look isn't quite that bad,

**[check the Pen](http://codepen.io/maio/pen/doZpZd)** ( tested only on Chrome)

---

**HTML**

```
<section>
<p >Stop, I'm getting dizzy!</p>
</section>
```

---

**SCSS**

```
section{
  animation-name: spinner;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}

@keyframes spinner {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

$colors: #000,#111,#222,#333,#444,#555,#666,#777,#888,#999,#aaa,#bbb;

@for $i from 1 through length($colors) {
    p:nth-child( #{$i} ){
       transform: translateZ(- $i+px);
       color: (nth($colors, $i));

    }
}
```

---

**JS**

```
var p = document.querySelector('p');

for(var i = 0 ; i<13 ; i++){
var node = document.createElement('p');
var child = "Stop, I'm getting dizzy!";
  child = document.createTextNode(child);
  node.appendChild(child);
p.parentNode.appendChild(node);
}
```

```css
section {
  animation-name: spinner;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}

p:last-child {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: silver;
}

@keyframes spinner {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

p:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateZ(-1px);
  color: #000;
}

p:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateZ(-2px);
  color: #111;
}

p:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateZ(-3px);
  color: #222;
}

p:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translateZ(-4px);
  color: #333;
}

p:nth-child(5) {
  transform: translateZ(-5px);
  color: #444;
}

p:nth-child(6) {
  transform: translateZ(-6px);
  color: #555;
}

p:nth-child(7) {
  transform: translateZ(-7px);
  color: #666;
}

p:nth-child(8) {
  transform: translateZ(-8px);
  color: #777;
}

p:nth-child(9) {
  transform: translateZ(-9px);
  color: #888;
}

p:nth-child(10) {
  transform: translateZ(-10px);
  color: #999;
}

p:nth-child(11) {
  transform: translateZ(-11px);
  color: #aaa;
}

p:nth-child(12) {
  transform: translateZ(-12px);
  color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
 <section>
   <p>Stop, I'm getting dizzy!</p>
   <p>Stop, I'm getting dizzy!</p>
   <p>Stop, I'm getting dizzy!</p>
   <p>Stop, I'm getting dizzy!</p>
   <p>Stop, I'm getting dizzy!</p>
   <p>Stop, I'm getting dizzy!</p>
   <p>Stop, I'm getting dizzy!</p>
   <p>Stop, I'm getting dizzy!</p>
   <p>Stop, I'm getting dizzy!</p>
   <p>Stop, I'm getting dizzy!</p>
   <p>Stop, I'm getting dizzy!</p>
   <p>Stop, I'm getting dizzy!</p>
   </section>
```

Comment: Whilst this effect does look better than a pure css solution, I am limited to pure css.

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King the JS and SCSS part is only programmatic; the final output is just HTML and CSS

Comment: You're using JS to create 13 `p` tags. I cannot add more HTML elements and I am limited to CSS (no JS).

Answer (score 2):

I have added extra layers of the text using `:before` and `:after` elements, and I have offset their Y axis by -3deg and 3deg respectively. The result is that the text now has a "sort of" depth. If I use a shorter string (e.g. "RPK") I can increase the offset to about 7deg and still have an OK look. However, this only gives the outer edges an extra "depth".

```css
#spinner {
  animation-name: spinner;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:2em;
}
#spinner:after,
#spinner:before {
  content:"Stop, I'm getting dizzy!";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  transform: rotateY(2deg);
}
#spinner:before {
  transform: rotateY(-2deg);
}
#spinner,
#spinner:after,
#spinner:before {
  font-weight:narrow;
}
@keyframes spinner {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="spinner">Stop, I'm getting dizzy!</p>
```

In this version I have changed the `rotate` property for `translateZ`. Again, this effect looks better with a shorter string.

```css
#spinner {
  animation-name: spinner;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
}
#spinner:after,
#spinner:before {
  content: "Stop, I'm getting dizzy!";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateZ(3px);
}
#spinner:before {
  transform:translateZ(-3px);
}
@keyframes spinner {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="spinner">Stop, I'm getting dizzy!</p>
```

I'm not going to accept this as the answer because it does not give me the exact effect I am after. I am sure someone out there will find the perfect method :o)

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted CSS-driven rotating text, though my approach was different. I'll add it in case it helps others:

```css
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg) rotateX(360deg);
  }
}

#shared-loader {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  perspective: 400px;
  transform: scale(0.2);
}
    
.cube {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ(-100px);
  transition: transform 2s;
  animation: spin 6s linear infinite;
}

.cube-face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background: #de662c;
}

.cube-face-front  { transform: rotateY(  0deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube-face-right  { transform: rotateY( 90deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube-face-back   { transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube-face-left   { transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube-face-top    { transform: rotateX( 90deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube-face-bottom { transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px); }
```

```html
<div id="shared-loader">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="cube-face cube-face-front">Y</div>
    <div class="cube-face cube-face-back">Y</div>
    <div class="cube-face cube-face-right">Y</div>
    <div class="cube-face cube-face-left">Y</div>
    <div class="cube-face cube-face-top">Y</div>
    <div class="cube-face cube-face-bottom">Y</div>
  </div>
</div>
```